# Selenium IDE - Cannot copy emails

Tags: javascript

Hi I read the article below to copy the value from one field to another using Selenium IDE, but that code is not doing anything

[Selenium: How to copy values from field1 to field2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808378/selenium-how-to-copy-values-from-field1-to-field2)

I have 2 emails fields -

Email1 - Enter the email address, for which I am using - javascript{"Test+" + Math.floor(Math.random()*11111) + "@test.com";}

Email2 - Verify Email - I have to enter the same email from Email1 to this field for which I tried the above code, which is not helping me.

Can you please help me with this code. Above is my scenario. Please help me.

Thank You

Answer (score 4):

Try using the StoreEval command first before entering values into each field.

For example,

```
storeEval|["Test+" + Math.floor(Math.random()*11111) + "@test.com"]|email
type     |//*[@fieldname='email1']                                 |${email}
type     |//*[@fieldname='email2']                                 |${email}
```