# How to emulate CTRL + A & CTRL + C in selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I can't figure out how to do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to select all the text in a text box and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy it. I tried to do it using the following [see image] but it didnt' work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7808871/2838451) link for your solution.

[Here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/flow-control/) is firefox add-ons for advance on selenium IDE.

To integrate in java code for select whole page you need to do,

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"));
```

For copy contents from element,

```
element.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "a");
element.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "c");
```

For past contents to element,

```
element.Clear();
element.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "v");
```

Comment: with the link, it works fine for copy paste. But what helps for selecting all. I want to select all the content available in the location